# How to pop up PopUp control at center in silverlight

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, popup, silverlight-5.0

I am trying to pop up a PopUp control which contains some buttons but unfortunately it is popuped at the  left top corner when i run my application. I mean at (0,0)[in explain (x,y) axis].

My code to do so is:

```
<Popup x:Name="myPopup" Margin="-34,0,-31,0" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" Height="78" VerticalAlignment="center" HorizontalAlignment="center">
    <Border Background="Silver" BorderThickness="2" BorderBrush="Black" Height="224" Width="371">
        // Here is a grid which contains all my buttons and otherthing on popup
    </Border>
</Popup>
```

**Could some one please help me in poping it up at center ?** (It do not do even i have done `HorizontalAlignment="center"` and `VerticalAlignment="center"`).

Comment: When I saw this question pop up in my feed about popping up a pop up pop up I almost threw my pop up. Instead I called my pop up to let him know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`ChildWindow`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.childwindow(v=vs.95).aspx), which would automatically present in center of the screen

or if you want to manually put the popup in center, you can manually adjust [`HorizontalOffset`](https://www.google.lk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CBoQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Flibrary%2Fsystem.windows.controls.primitives.popup.horizontaloffset(v%3Dvs.110).aspx&ei=zvHIU7xE0Ly6BOPPgaAJ&usg=AFQjCNG64P-k7OfGD01nsQMh6KmvSmZ81Q&sig2=IzMpWTM2noeyWIo-2T-T5g&bvm=bv.71198958,d.c2E) and [`VerticalOffset`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.popup.verticaloffset(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
double positioningX = (Application.Current.Host.Content.ActualWidth / 2) - (widthOfDialog / 2);
double positioningY = (Application.Current.Host.Content.ActualHeight / 2) - (heightOfDialog / 2);
if (positioningX > 0)
    popup.HorizontalOffset = positioningX;
if (positioningY > 0)
    popup.VerticalOffset = positioningY;
```

Comment: @Sajetharan when i use childwindow it popups at center but makes the area around pop up less visible. So i have to avoid that. Thats why i used PopUp control.

Comment: @user3735822 did you try the above one

Comment: i tried with ChildWindow but it pop ups nicely but it  makes the rest of the area less visible on Pop-up. DO YOU KNOW ANY WAY TO MAKE AREA AROUND CHILD BOX POP UP visible  ? (because PopUp control is also not accepted by my tutor because it do not pop up like meassageBox). Or if you know any other alernative to achieve this.

Comment: actually i want to have 3 buttons on a message box nO?yES AND CANCEL

Answer (score 0):

Use VerticalOffset and HorizontalOffset

Comment: i guess this is for WPF

Comment: i have already described this in my post, pls speficy your edits

Answer (score 0):

In my case solved it this way:

```
 double width = Convert.ToDouble(HtmlPage.Window.Eval("screen.width"));
                double height = Convert.ToDouble(HtmlPage.Window.Eval("screen.height"));

                AdvertisingControl ac = new AdvertisingControl(); // Your user control here..

                this.p = new Popup()
                {
                    VerticalOffset = (height - ac.Height) / 2.0,
                    HorizontalOffset = (width - ac.Width) / 2.0,
                    Width = ac.Width,
                    Height = ac.Height,
                    Child = ac,
                };

                this.p.IsOpen = true;
```